# Chaining Permission Intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

What's the correct way to chain from a permission intent to another with Dialogflow?

I've got two intents setup:

```
app.intent('ask_for_permission', async (conv) => {
  return conv.ask(new Permission({
    context: 'to get your location',
    permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION',
  })); 
})


app.intent('confirm_permissions', async (conv, params, confirmationGranted) => {
  conv.ask(`I think you gave me permission? ${params} ${confirmationGranted}`)
})
```

And within the Dialogflow control panel I have it setup so the `ask_for_permission` intent follows on to the `confirm_permissions` intent like so:

[image: Dialogflow UI]

But whenever I trigger the ask_for_permission intent, the user gets asked if they want to share their location, but responding with either `yes` or `no` doesn't actually trigger the user to move onto the next intent.

[image]

Here it is in the simulator:

[image]

Where am I going wrong here? I want to trigger the secondary intent and be able to get the location data of the user if they confirmed the use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up a few concepts here. It looks like your `ask_for_permission` Intent is triggering the [Permission helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information) - that part seems fine.

As part of this, you're setting a `confirm_permissions` *context*. A Context is different than an Intent. What you're saying by setting the Output Context the way you are is that you're in a state named "confirm_permissions", and Intents that should only be triggered in this state may be evaluated when processing responses.

Instead, I think you want to create a `confirm_permissions` *intent*. In Dialogflow, the response will be an `actions_intent_PERMISSION` event, which you can create an Intent to handle. It might look something like this.

[image]

Of note here:

- The name of the Intent is whatever you want it to be, just like other Intents.
- The Event is the important bit, and must be set. This matches the name that is sent by Actions on Google as a special AoG Intent name (and replaces the periods with underscores).
- Since we are specifying an Event, we do *not* use training phrases.
- Don't forget to enable fulfillment.

On the fulfillment side, your code looks like it should work.

The reason you were getting the "Say that one more time" and similar replies is that these are from the Default Fallback Intent. Since no Intents were setup to match the permission Event, it used the Fallback Intent that was defined.